# How to change the color of a line with different pattern classifications in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, time-series, classification

I have a time series dataset that I used a machine learning algorithm to identify distinct patterns. I have that classified but I want to check it visually to see how it did.

How do I make a time series graph with different colors for each pattern classification OR what is the best way to visualize or check for accuracy with time series classification data?

The data basically looks like this

DATE   DEMAND     CLASSIFICATION
June 4 678        1

Generally the classification would look like this
0000000000000000011111111111111111110000000000000000000000000022222222222222222 etc.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tried:

1.Convert your (assuming str) data to int

```
x = '0000000000000000011111111111111111110000000000000000000000000022222222222222222'

x = [int(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

2.Create a color label array. I use here gray scale but you can use any RGB array.

```
import numpy as np

colors=[(i,i,i) for i in np.linspace(0,1,10)]
```

3.Use the bar plotting function with this color keys. I've tweaked some other properties in the bar function to make it a solid block.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(range(len(x)), np.ones(len(x),), width = 1, linewidth = 0, color = [colors[i] for i in x])
```

Comment: Interesting Solution. I will give that a try.